# Idea - при включенном annotation processing повторно генерируются классы Dagger 2

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, dagger, lombok

Подключил Dagger 2:

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
}
```

Это все прекрасно работало, пока вдруг не появился Lombok:

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'

    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0"
}
```

Проблема в том, что он требует включенный флаг Enable annotation processing, иначе Idea не понимает откуда взяться методам, cгенерированными ломбоком.

Но если включить Annotation processing, то файлы dagger генерируются дважды (насколько я понял в первый раз через apt, второй раз через annotation processing или наоборот):

```
Error:(18, 29) java: Could not generate unknown file: Attempt to recreate a file for type имя_класса
```

Получается так:

- выключаем annotation processing - отваливается lombok
- включаем annotation processing - отваливается dagger
- включаем annotation processing + удаляем `apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'` - отваливается сборка в gradle

Answer (score 0):

Не решение проблемы, сколько workaround. Зайти в настройки Idea, Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner -> Delegate build/run to gradle.